# Android button disable till the Toast is seen

Tags: android, toast

I have a button which shows a progress dialog, on end of progress dialog, a toast is shown. 
I want the button to be diabled when the progress dialog and the toast are seen on the UI. i.e. after the toast is gone i want my button to be enabled again

Can anybody suggest what to do

Comment: How can we help if you don't share the codes ?

Comment: post your code here if you have implemented it?

Comment: I havent implemented. Please tell me how to implement

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you show the toast, set the button clickable to false, and start this timer task. The method of the class Timer namely schedule(), is such that it is executed after the provided time. In this case i passed the time as Toast.LENGTH _SHORT

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
   Timer time = new Timer();
   time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                     your_button.setClickable(true);
                  }
             });
         }
    },Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  //// If your toast is for length short.
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code before the progress dialog starts

```
Button myBtn=findViewById(R.id.button1);
myBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//myBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

After Toast.makeText() is called, put the below code:

```
myBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//myBtn.setEnabled(true);
```

Note that setVisibility will make the button visible/invisible, setEnabled(false) will turn your button to non-clcikable mde.

Comment: yes i have already done that.... the thing now is... once the dialog comes the button is diabled. But after the Progres dialog is gone i display a toast. So i want after my toast is gone the button shoudl be enabled..... I was using a TimerTask...but i am not able to update the UI i.e. enable the button in TimerTask...Can anyone pls help

Otherwise the user keep on pressiing the button again n again. I want to avoid that

Comment: That is what i have specified to you. Only after Toast.makeText() Enable the button.

Comment: no once the toast is gone i want to enable it.. so how to find that when the toast is gone.. 

Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mToast.show();

once this mToast is gone, i will write 
mButton.setEnabled(true);

Comment: does anyone knows how to know if the toast is gone so that once that has gone from the UI i will enable my button

Comment: Ok, got your point. Theoretically, LENGTH_LONG = 3.5 seconds and LENGTH_SHORT = 2 seconds. So what you can do is, the next statement after Toast.makeText() is Thread.sleep(3500) for LENGTH_LONG and Thread.sleep(2000) for LENGTH_SHORT, surround it with a try catch and i hope this will work.

Comment: it didnt work dear :) I did the same in the very beginning ... That is the reason i am asking for an alternative :)

Comment: Try doing the samething in a new thread, rather than in the main thread.